# How to tell when interaction is in after call work state?

Tags: genesys, workspace-desktop-edition

Is it possible to tell inside a chain of command if the current main interaction is in "After Call Work" mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out if you can get the interaction object it's pretty easy. If it's not passed as a parameter in the the Execute method use the IInteractionManager to get it:

1) Get the IInteractionVoice object

From the parameters passed into Execute:

```
var interaction = parameters["CommandParameter"] as IInteraction;
```

or Inject an IInteractionManager in the constructor and use that:

```
IInteractionManager.Interactions
```

Then read the IInteraction.IsItPossibleToMarkDone property.